# ftp server offering http access?

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, ftp

Is there an FTP server that can also provide access via HTTP? Or what do I need to do to set up the mirror of FTP through HTTP access ? Some of my clients cannot access our FTP because of corporate policy and cannot get updates from me. However, they can use HTTP.

Currently I use filezilla because it was fast/easy to set up but would switch to something with more flexibility.

Comment: please suggest or fix tags as necessary.

Comment: Which OS is the server running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used CrushFTP running on Windows 2003. It works on other platforms as well and no clinet needed  [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/features.html)

Many features for secure access with HTTPS and others. Many other great features, low cost and great support.  Have not tried V5 but last version has been great.  Worth a look

Comment: Looks good. The cost isn't prohibitive either.

Comment: CrushFTP uses webdav - don't most places block that?

Comment: Crush uses Webdav among several other protocols.  No router changes necessary if you use HTTPS/HTTP already. Naturally, you can use otehr protocols that could have issues

Comment: I set it up in a test emv today. Was really easy to use. I need to fiddle a bit more because I am not getting quite the transfer rates I was hoping for. But it's ma trade off accept for the ease of use.

Comment: Reach out to the developer with questions or concerns.  He is VERY respomsive. I have been amazed at the quick response to questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set up almost any FTP or web server on the platform you are running on to point to the same directory that hold your updates.

Comment: I thought about this. I would need to manage I'd and passwords separately for both their FTP and web access?

Comment: depends on the platform, on windows the same id's but you would have to put them in the right groups for both FTP and http access (of course that could be the same group)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would count as mirroring but you can have Apache or Lighttpd (I'm assuming with Lity) that you can have a symlink to your FTP directory so its a live mirror without any work.

However, if you're not using public FTP files and require passwords, you'll probably need to do some .htaccess magic but its still possible (at least in Apache, I'm not sure about Lighttpd)